# OutlinedButton exception when trying to set max size

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I'm trying to create something like the below image:

[image]

I used two `OutlinedButton` in a row:

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          OutlinedButton(
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: colorBackButton,
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                      (states) => Size(65.0, 65.0)))),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0)),

          OutlinedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Next',
                  style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                    return colorPrimaryButton;
                  }),
                }),

        ])
```

This has led me to this result:

[image]

I tried to wrap the `Next` button with `Sizedbox.expand` and also add a `minimumSize` to the button style:

`minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => const Size.fromHeight(55.0))`

Both results with a `BoxConstraints forces an infinite width. These invalid constraints were provided to RenderPhysicalShape's layout() function by t`

Digging into the exception, it's written:

`The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 55.0<=h<=Infinity)`

How can I make the `Next` button fill the entire row's space (discluding the padding of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap with `Expanded` widget to get maximum available space.

```dart
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
        style: ButtonStyle(
          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
            (states) => const Size(65.0, 65.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
          child: OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Next',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white)),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepPurple),
              fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                (states) => const Size(65.0, 65.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

[image]

You can play with padding. Also, you can use [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html).

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I think the issue was the padding that was supposed to be insied the expanded (as I think using `Sizedbox.expande` should yield the same result as expanded. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try use expanded widget  Wrap next button with expanded like that

```
Expanded(
          child: OutlinedButton(
            child: Text(
              'Next',
              style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                return colorPrimaryButton;
              }),
            }),
        ),
```